# Python - change multiple elements in list based on indices

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python.. My question: I have a list rt, and a list with indices rtInd, which varies in size and content.

For all the indices in rtInd, I want to change the corresponding elements in rt.

Example: `rt = [10,20,30,40]; rtInd = [2,3]`

What I want:

```
rt[2] = 30 + x

rt[3] = 40 + x
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Amy

Comment: does `for i in rtInd: rt[i] += x` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of indices, and you have `x`, you can loop through and update the values at the corresponding indices:

```py
rt = [10,20,30,40]
rtInd = [2,3]
x = 10

for i in rtInd:
    rt[i] += x

# result:
# rt = [10, 20, 40, 50]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If `rt` is a `numpy` array, you could index with the `list` (or `numpy.array`) of indices itself (must *not* be a `tuple`, to be clear, due to `tuple`s being used for multidimensional access, not a set of indices to modify):

```
# Setup
rt = numpy.array([10, 20, 30, 40], dtype=np.int64)
rtInd = [2, 3]  # Or numpy.array([2, 3])
x = 123  # Arbitrary value picked

# Actual work
rt[rtInd] += x
```

and that will push the work to a single operation inside `numpy` (potentially improving performance).

That said, `numpy` is a pretty heavyweight dependency; if you're not already relying on `numpy`, I'd stick to the simple loop described in [M Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569559/364696).